generating list satisfying linear integer constraint in python
In python, I have a list w of integers, and I would like to efficiently generate all lists of (non-negative) integers such that their sum with weights in w is equal to a certain value a, that is
 sum([i*j for i,j in zip(w,f)]) == a
ie the product of w with f is fixed by a. Here everything is int valued, and positive or zero. The brute force version would be to use itertools:
from itertools import product

a = 20
w = [1,1,3,3]
rslt = []
for f in product(range(a+1), repeat=len(w)):
   if sum([i*j for i,j in zip(w,f)]) == a:
      rslt.append(list(f))

print(rslt)

This however scales very badly with the value of a. Is there a way of making generating rslt efficiently? I couldn't find a way to impose constraint with itertools directly. Mathematically, starting with a known vector w, I want to find all vectors f such that their dot product is fixed by a.
I came up with the idea of a recursive function that compute the difference from a at a given stage of the loop, but I'm having trouble with the implementation. If it's possible to have an implementation that also does arbitrary constraints (e.g. quadratic), that would be fantastic.

Can there be negative numbers?

There was a typo, and all variables are non-negative integers (so zero or positive).

Since this is flaged "recursion" I guess this solution is acceptable
def bb(a, w):
    # If target is 0, then all remaining numbers should be 0
    if a==0: return [(0,)*len(w)]
    # If target is non 0, then we need some remaining number, otherwise, empty set of solutions
    if len(w)==0: return []
    rslt=[]
    # branch & bound part. Just try with any possibility for first number
    # combined with (recursion) any possibility for the rest
    for first in range(0, a+1, w[0]):
        for rest in bb(a-first, w[1:]):
            rslt.append((first//w[0],)+rest)
    return rslt

On my machine, with a=60, that is 0.03 second, vs 10 for yours.
(Plus, it has solutions that yours is missing. Such as the (0,20,0,0) mentioned in comments. I assume non-negative numbers)
Edit: generator
I see that this is also flagged generator, so I guess this is more what is expected
def bb(a, w):
    if a==0:
        yield (0,)*len(w)
        return
    if len(w)==0: return
    for first in range(0, a+1, w[0]):
        for rest in bb(a-first, w[1:]):
            yield (first//w[0],)+rest


The usual approach is to use recursion and memoization, so to avoid calculation the same partial solution over and over again. For memoization you can use functools.cache:
from functools import cache

def solve(weights, target):
    n = len(weights)

    @cache
    def recur(target, num_weights):
        if target == 0:
            return [[0] * num_weights]
        results = []
        if num_weights > 0:
            num_weights -= 1
            for freq, remainder in enumerate(range(target, -1, -weights[num_weights])):
                for recresult in recur(remainder, num_weights):
                    results.append([*recresult, freq])
        return results
        
    return recur(target, n)

For given w and a, call as:
result = solve(w, a)

